# NullPointerException thrown on transaction commit attempt after method returns

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm getting a really strange NullPointerException when saving my Entity and I can't seem to figure out why.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.getHashCode(AbstractType.java:129)
at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$groupingBy$53(Collectors.java:1127)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.groupByEqualityHash(PersistentBag.java:196)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.equalsSnapshot(PersistentBag.java:151)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionEntry.dirty(CollectionEntry.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CollectionEntry.preFlush(CollectionEntry.java:182)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.lambda$prepareCollectionFlushes$0(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:195)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.forEachCollectionEntry(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1091)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareCollectionFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:194)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:86)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.onAutoFlush(DefaultAutoFlushEventListener.java:50)
at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.autoFlushIfRequired(SessionImpl.java:1323)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1403)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1558)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1526)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
[...] the rest was cut for readability (if you think it's really important, I'll edit and add the whole exception, but I think it's the first line that says it all)
```

This is the higher exception that's thrown because of the one above:

```
org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:542)
```

and this nested one:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convertCommitException
```

I've been running around in circles all day trying to figure out why this was happening and the internet didn't help because most of similar questions remain unanswered. What makes matters worse is Spring's abstraction makes it impossible to debug!

Here's the scenario:
I have an `EventEntity` which I'm trying to update, along with its child entity `EventAttachmentEntity`. I've turned on logging to follow what's happening and pretty much the expected happens:

- I've updated eventEntity (update SQL generated)
- I've inserted new attachments for the updated event (insert SQL generated with right event_id)

And then the strange thing happens, my method reaches the end and then this exception occurs.

The method is abstracted for disclosure reasons, but the main flow is as follows:

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void updateEvent(EventEntity event) {
    EventEntity updatedEvent = eventRepository.save(event);

    EventAttachmentEntity newAttachment = new EventAttachmentEntity(updatedEvent);
    // fill attachment [...]
    newAttachment.setEvent(updatedEvent);
    eventAttachmentRepository.save(newAttachment); 

    System.out.println("This line gets printed.");
}
```

So first I save the updated parent and then I create new child, set the parent, and then save it. All the SQLs confirm this is what happens. The last line prints as well, meaning nothing broke in the previous saving methods. Then it reaches the end and BOOM! exception.

Here's my entities:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "event", schema = "xxx")
@DynamicUpdate
public class EventEntity {
    private long id;
    private Collection<EventAttachmentEntity> eventAttachments;

    // other properties abstracted

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "event")
    public Collection<EventAttachmentEntity> getEventAttachments() {
        return this.eventAttachments;
    }

    public void setEventAttachments(Collection<EventAttachmentEntity> eventAttachments) {
        this.eventAttachments = eventAttachments;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "event_attachment", schema = "xxx")
public class EventAttachmentEntity {
    private long id;
    private String filename;
    private String contentType;
    private long filesize;
    private EventEntity event;

   // other properties abstracted

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public EventEntity getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(EventEntity event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        EventAttachmentEntity that = (EventAttachmentEntity) o;
        return id == that.id &&
                filesize == that.filesize &&
                Objects.equals(filename, that.filename) &&
                Objects.equals(contentType, that.contentType);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, filename, contentType, filesize);
    }
}
```

I've included `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods for EventAttachmentEntity because the exception obviously happens at `getHashCode()`, but when I place the breakpoint there, it's actually the Object whose getHashCode is called that's null.

**Important note:** I've checked whether any variable in my code was null or hasn't been properly autowired - everything's fine. Like I said, the method itself runs smoothly until it reaches the end and tries to commit the transaction. That's when it breaks.

Also, when I try to update only the event (without attachments), everything works okay. Another case I've tried is to save a similar relationship of this event (not shown here) and it also works fine. So it's *something* to do with attachments and I can't figure out what it is!

What's also weird is if I remove `@Transactional` from this method, it throws the same exception. There is no `@Transactional` marked method that's calling `updateEvent()`, so I'm not sure how this is even happening.

Please, I need *any kind of suggestion* as to what might be the issue so I can try it, because right now I pretty much hit the wall and can't continue.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the whole code and we can only guess what you have there. According tp the shown code the member variable `EventEntity.eventAttachments` is not initialized. When you try to persist such entity, this can lead to NPE.

**Solution**

Initialize it, e.g. as follows:

```
private Collection<EventAttachmentEntity> eventAttachments = new HashSet<>();
```

Also in `setEventAttachments` make sure that `eventAttachment` remains not null no matter what argument is passed to this setter.

Comment: I know, but this is pretty much the gist of it. I don't think it not being initialized in the entity is the issue because all relationships are defined like this (it's actually done by IDE from db schema) and I'm not adding to the collection itself (which, if it was null, would result in NPE), I'm preserving the object straight to db. However, I tried with this suggestion as well, same thing happens :/

Answer (score 0):

In `updateEvent(EventEntity updatedEvent)` method `updatedEvent` is persisted to database `eventRepository.save(updatedEvent)`, but the documentation of [S save(S entity)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-) method says:

> Saves a given entity. Use the returned instance for further operations as the save operation might have changed the entity instance completely.

From the code you posted so far it seems that you do not use the returned by `save` method entity instance as recommended:

```
eventRepository.save(updatedEvent);

EventAttachmentEntity newAttachment = new EventAttachmentEntity(updatedEvent);
// fill attachment [...]
newAttachment.setEvent(updatedEvent);
```

I'm not sure if that could be the reason for the error, but the proper way to handle the update would be something along these lines:

```
updatedEvent = eventRepository.save(updatedEvent); // update updatedEvent 

EventAttachmentEntity newAttachment = new EventAttachmentEntity(updatedEvent);
// fill attachment [...]
newAttachment.setEvent(updatedEvent);
```

Comment: I tried that as well :( still the same thing happens. But you're right, it's the right way to do the update anyway, so I'll edit my question accordingly.